# On change hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onchange, hidden

I have the following hidden input in a form tag:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="myID" name="pn" value="">
```

On change, if the value of this input is "abcd", then do something. But I can´t make it work.

This is my script:

```html
$("#myID").change(function () {
  var myVAR = $("#myID").val();
  if (myVAR == "abcd") {
    // my code here
      }
});
```

Can someone help pls?
Thanks much.

Comment: How are you handling the event function? The jQuery code you put there is only triggering a change event, but you are not changing the input's value nor adding an event handler to it. Ex: `$('#myID').on('change', function (){})`

Comment: How does one change the value in a hidden input?

Comment: on change do what?

Comment: You have an hidden input and you bound a change event. Change events only fire when the user changes the data. They do not fire when JavaScript changes the data.

Comment: It's possible to do, but to find the solution we must know how exactly you are changing the value of your hidden input, so post more code.

Answer (score 1):

Because the input is hidden, when you change the value, you need to trigger the change: `$("#myID").val('abcd').trigger('change');`

```js
$("#myID").change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() == "abcd") {
    alert("Found 'abcd'");
      }
});
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  $("#myID").val('abcd').trigger('change');
  alert($("#myID").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="myID" name="pn" value="">
<button>Set abcd for myID</button>
```